# A basic question trying to make a structure

Tags: c, structure

What I'm trying to do is get student's name and score in three subjects in the form of a structure array and print their name and average score.

Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[5];
    int Kor; //yeah the three subjects
    int Eng;
    int Math;
}data;

double avg(int a, int b, int c) //to get the average
{
    double m;
    m = (a + b + c) / 3;
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    data group[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %d %d", group[i].name, group[i].Kor, group[i].Eng, group[i].Math);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("%s %lf\n", group[j].name, avg(group[j].Kor, group[j].Eng, group[j].Math));
    }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get error messages?

Comment: `%d` in the `scanf` expects an `int *`, but `group[i].Kor` is an `int`, change it to `&group[i].Kor` and the others too.

Comment: `char name[5]` this allows to have names with up to 4 characters. That's probably not enough. If you enter names longer than 4 characters, you'll get a buffer overflow which will result un undefined behaviour (all kind of strange things may happen). Try with `char name[100]`. Also `group[i].Kor, group[i].Eng, group[i].Math` -> `&group[i].Kor, &group[i].Eng, &group[i].Math` in `scanf`

Comment: Additionally, your `avg` returns a double but its result is truncated. Divide the sum of scores by 3.0 to avoid unnecessary roundings.

Comment: You have gotten downvotes because it is not clear what the problem was, and you did not provide the log of a session of the program running - what you entered as input and what you got as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you should make sure and do is compile with **most/all compiler warning flags on**. In your case, when I compiled your program with GCC, using the flags `-W -Wall -Wextra`, I [got](https://godbolt.org/z/h8yJNu) the following warnings:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:23:20: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

   23 |         scanf("%s %d %d %d", group[i].name, group[i].Kor, group[i].Eng, group[i].Math);

      |                   ~^                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                    |                                |

      |                    int *                            int
```

and the same warning for `group[i].Eng` and `group[i].Math`.

These compiler warnings are very often actually errors of yours, which, at runtime, will result in the program crashing or producing garbage. In your case, you need to pass the *address* of the value you want to read from the input.

This does not mean that's the only issue with your code, but you should really let the *compiler* help you before asking *us* for help.

Comment: thks for real, i didn't know there exists sth like GCC

Comment: @jmjm: The way to thank someone for an answer is to upvote it (if it's useful) and accept it (if it answers your question).

Comment: My bad, didn't notice there is a button for accept / upvoted your answer before, but the site says it doesn't count due to my reputation which is under 15

Answer (score -1):

I change the `scanf`, '&' operator is used to access to the address in the memory location. scanf("%d",&a) means that the value entered from the keyboard must be stored in the memory LOCATION where which is given the name 'a'.

and change the `calculating function` of the average because you are using the integer division version of operator/, which takes 2 ints and returns an int. In order to use the double version, which returns a double, at least one of the ints must be casted to a double.

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct
{
    char name[5];
    int Kor; //yeah the three subjects
    int Eng;
    int Math;
}data;

double avg(int a, int b, int c) //to get the average
{
    double m;
    m = (a + b + c) / 3.0;
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    data group[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("enter your name ,Kor grade ,Eng grade ,Math grade\n");
        scanf("%s %d  %d %d", group[i].name, &group[i].Kor, &group[i].Eng, &group[i].Math);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("name:%s avg:%lf\n", group[j].name, avg(group[j].Kor, group[j].Eng, group[j].Math));
    }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some context what you changed and why. Your answer is supposed to help the OP and others coming here.

Comment: I change the scanf, '&' operator is used to access to the address in the memory location. scanf("%d",&a) means that the value entered from the keyboard must be stored in the memory LOCATION where which is given the name 'a'.

Comment: I also change the calculating of the average because you are using the integer division version of operator/, which takes 2 ints and returns an int. In order to use the double version, which returns a double, at least one of the ints must be casted to a double.

Comment: Please don't post comments, edit your answer, please. Nobody cares to read comments.